# Wait for a response from a function

Tags: discord.js

I tried making a command in my discord.js bot, however the embed with the info gets sent BEFORE all the variables were set (this is beacuse I use Firestore, it takes a second to get the data)
The function would look something like this:

```js
function getData(){
    var level = 0

    let levels = database.collection('guilds').doc(message.guild.id).collection('levels').doc(person.id)

    levels.get().then((q) => { 
        if(q.exists){ 
            let data = q.data()

            level = data.level

            return level
        }
    })
}

message.channel.send(getData())
// would send 0 because the function didnt get the data in time
```

How can I call a function and then wait for a response?
I tried messing around with async and await but I dont really know how to use them, which kept throwing errors.

Comment: it would send 0 because that is what you define in the function. Are you sure that whatever you do with that level works? You need to provide more code for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: it does get set after a while, I tried, but Ill post more of the code

Comment: from what I can tell it looks like you are fetching the level from a database, then if it exists return it. Generally you can use `await` in front of a function to make sure it returns something before continueing. That only works within an `async` function though so make sure you have that. In your case that would probably be where you access the database, so `let levels = await database.collection.{...}`. I cannot test this because I cannot recreate your problem completly which is why this isn't an answer ;)

Comment: This is exactly what I dont know how to do. This is a command in a command handler:



```
module.exports = {

   execute(message, args, command, database){
      // do all the stuff from the post here
   }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you have two options here. Either use `async` before `execute(message, args, etc.)` or use it before your function. What you need to do depends on how your code is written. I don't know that so I can't tell you.

Comment: I tried doing `async function getData(){ // stuff here }` and then calling it with `await getData()` but that STILL errors

Comment: it errors? as what?